# drawing a value from a vector r

Tags: r, random, sample

After removing the values from the vector from 1 to 100 I have the following vector:

```
 w
 [1]  2  5 13 23 24 39 41 47 48 51 52 58 61 62 70 71 72 90
```

I am now trying to draw values from this vector with the sample function

```
    for(x in roznica)
{
  
  if(licznik_2 != licznik_1 )
  {
    
    roznica_proces_2 <- sample(1:w, roznica)
  } else {
    roznica_proces_2 <- NA
  } 
}
```

I tried various combinations with the sample

Comment: what's wrong with `sample(roznica)`? or  `sample(roznica, 1)`?

Comment: What are  `licznik_2` and `licznik_2` and how would you like to use them?

Comment: What is your goal, ie in what way do you want to draw samples? It's hard to know from this which parts are or are not working as you intend.

Comment: I am only concerned with the sample function itself: 

I will show an example :
`w
[1] 31`
and now I want to draw 1 number from that in ( which is 31)
`proces_nr_2 <- sample(w, 1)`
What does he get?
`proces_nr_2
[1] 26`

Answer (score 0):

If `w` is the name of the vector then you would NOT use `sample(1:w, ...)`. For one thing 1:w doesn't really amke sense since the `:` operator expects its second argument to be a single number, while `w` is apparently on the order of 15 values. Depending on what `roznica` is (and hopefully it is a single integer) then you might use:

```
sample(w, roznica)  # returns a vector of length roznica's value of randomly ordered values in `w`.
```

The other problem is that you are currently overwirign any values from prior iterations of the for loop. So you might want to use:

```
 roznica_proces_2[roznica] <- sample(1:w, roznica)
```

You would of course need to have initialized roznica_proces_2, perhaps with:

```
roznica_proces_2 <- list()
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your query in the comment :

> I am only concerned with the sample function itself: I will show an example : w [1] 31 and now I want to draw 1 number from that in ( which is 31) proces_nr_2 <- sample(w, 1) What does he get? proces_nr_2 [1] 26

The reason that happens is because when a vector is of length 1 the sampling takes from 1 to that number. It is explained in the help page of `?sample`.

> If x has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and x >= 1, sampling via sample takes place from 1:x

So if you have only 1 number to `sample` just return that number directly instead of passing it in `sample`.